# Are void pointers safe?

Tags: c, void-pointers, bit-shift

I'm working on bitwise operations for unsigned integer types. I want to write left-circular-shift function for uint8_t, uint16_t, ... ,uint64_t types.

My solution is:

```
(void*) left_circular_shift(void* number, size_t size);
```

If size is 64, I convert void* to uint64_t etc., but many programmers avoid using void*. Should I implement that function for all unsigned integer types?

Comment: A type-generic macro might be a useful approach.

Comment: You want to convert `void*` to `uint64_t` or to `uint64_t*` ? This makes a big difference.

Answer (score 2):

In your case you can't use void*. If you have a generic function that takes void* you will not be able to measure the size of what you got (how does it know where your number ends?), so you won't be able to cast it back.

Regarding Void* being "safe": The reason why you might have heard that it was "not safe" is because it being a generic no-type pointer it requires you to know exactly with what kind of data you're dealing with (you need to cast it back). So it is more prone to cause unexpected and weird errors if used carelessly.

The simple way to do this is to use one function for each. Another option is, like other people suggested, use a generic macro, regarding that, this might interest you: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-gcc-hacks/index.html

Answer (score 1):

In C++ it makes sense to implement this function for all unsigned types (keeping the same function name). In C it is not possible, but you can create different functions for all types, like `left_circular_shift_64` etc.

If you want to keep your interface, then you should convert `void*` to `uint64_t*` (not to `uint64_t`). It also might be useful to specify the `size` in bytes, not bits. Then the following construction can be used:

```
uint64_t value;
left_circular_shift(&value, sizeof(value));
```

This will help if, for instance, the type of `value` is changed to `uint32_t`.

Even though this option is valid and "safe", I would suggest to use distinct functions for each type. Some reasons to support this option:

- It is impossible to pass incorrect *data* to the function, e.g. `float`, `struct` or object.
- It is impossible to pass incorrect *size* to the function, e.g. 62. Thus, you do not need to invent what to do if the function gets strange input.
- You do not need to keep both parameters (pointer and size) sane, what reduces the possibility of bugs.
- In C++ there might be problems with casting `void*` to some complex types (e.g. classes with multiple inheritance), if you need to implement the shift operation for such types.

Answer (score 1):

There is no reason to use a pointer type at all for such a basic task. Use

```
inline
uintmax_t left_circular_shift(uintmax_t number, size_t size) {
  return /* your implementation goes here */
}
```

in a header file, and

```
extern inline uintmax_t left_circular_shift(uintmax_t number, size_t size);
```

in one .c file.

Then a modern compiler should be able to inline the calls in cases where `size` is a constant.

Answer (score 0):

Since you would need to dereference the void pointer in order to shift the number pointed to, this is not allowed, since e.g. pointers to differently sized numbers might be aligned differently.
Without knowing more details, this might be a case where a macro would be appropriate - this could change your number variable in place, if that is what you want.